# How to selectively render react table components?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

In the given code snippet I dont want to render the  component if the heading is equal to _id but the following conditional rendering results in no  rendering at all (empty table). What conditional statement should I use?

```
return <table className='paleBlueRows' cellPadding= {11} cellSpacing={11}>
        <thead>
            <tr>{data[0] && columns.map((heading) => {
            if(heading!=='_id') <th>{heading}</th>
})}</tr> .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the heading before mapping, or you can return `null` or `false` which [React will ignore](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering). Note that returning `undefined` (which is the same as not returning anything from a function) is not valid, and will cause React to emit a warning.

So, either:

```
return (
  <table className="paleBlueRows" cellPadding={11} cellSpacing={11}>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {data[0] &&
          columns
            .filter((heading) => heading !== "_id")
            .map((heading) => {
              return <th>{heading}</th>;
            })}
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
);
```

Or:

```
return (
  <table className="paleBlueRows" cellPadding={11} cellSpacing={11}>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {data[0] &&
          columns
            .filter((heading) => heading !== "_id")
            .map((heading) => {
              if (heading === "_id") return null;
              return <th>{heading}</th>;
            })}
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
);
```

Since you're rendering a list (with `.map()`), [make sure you set the `key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) of the element which you return from it. I don't know if `columns` can contain duplicate values, or anything else about its nature, so I can't make a precise suggestion. If `columns` contains no duplicate values, just set its value as the key so React knows which elements it needs to update if `columns` changes between renders.

```
return (
  <table className="paleBlueRows" cellPadding={11} cellSpacing={11}>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {data[0] &&
          columns
            .filter((heading) => heading !== "_id")
            .map((heading) => {
              return <th key={heading}>{heading}</th>;
            })}
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
);
```